# blocking background of a simple modal dialog in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog

i have a simple modal dialog in javascript i've buit by myself. The css is the following:

```
#overlay {
     visibility: hidden;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     text-align:center;
     z-index: 1000;
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

#show {
     width:300px;
     margin: 100px auto;
     background-color: #fff;
     border:1px solid #000;
     padding:15px;
     text-align:justify;
     font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
     font-size: 14px;
     font-weight: bold;
     line-height: 20px;
}
```

The javascript is the following:

```
function overlay() {
    var el = document.getElementById("overlay");
    el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
    if (el.style.visibility == "visible"){
        el.scrollIntoView();
    } 
}
```

The problem i have is bigger than it seems. I took this modal dialog code from the web to make a simple modal with only javascript and css but i wanted to build a full modal window, this window takes the 100% of the space viewable in the broser, but if you scroll down you can see the page that is still there behind the overlay, cause the overlay doesn't take the 100% of the webpage, but only 100% of the part that the user can see.

Do I have to inhibit the behaviour when the user scrolls down the overlay? How can i achieve this?

Any hint? Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using Bootstrap for your modal? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple, just change the css of the overlay:

```
#overlay {
     position: fixed;
     overflow: auto;
     ...
}
```

Then in the javascript function add these lines (outside of the "if" statement):

```
var b = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
b.style.overflow = (b.style.overflow == "") ? "hidden" : "";
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do:

```
$('#overlay').height($(document).height());
```

or give the overlay position fixed

```
#overlay{
position:fixed;
}
```